# Читает не весь xml файл

Tags: c#, xml

Не понимаю почему,но не загружает весь xml файл.
Всего загружает 21 итем. Если убрать 21 итем,будет загружать 19 итемов.

XML-Моделька:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<List>
<Item Id="10000001" Item="500010003" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="1" ItemType="0"/>
<Item Id="10000002" Item="601002011" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="2" ItemType="1"/>
<Item Id="10000003" Item="702001017" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="2"/>
<Item Id="10000004" Item="803007001" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="3"/>
<Item Id="10000005" Item="904007007" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="4"/>
<Item Id="10000006" Item="1001001003" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="5"/>
<Item Id="10000007" Item="1001001004" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="6"/>
<Item Id="10000008" Item="1104003003" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="7"/>
<Item Id="10000009" Item="1006001032" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="8"/>
<Item Id="10000010" Item="1103003010" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="0" ItemType="9"/>
<Item Id="10000011" Item="1200026000" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="1440" Type="2" StockType="1" ItemType="10"/>
<Item Id="10000012" Item="1200007000" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="1440" Type="2" StockType="1" ItemType="10"/>
<Item Id="10000013" Item="1103003003" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="1440" Type="2" StockType="1" ItemType="9"/>
<item Id="10000014" Item="1001001033" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="2" ItemType="6"/>
<Item Id="10000015" Item="300005032" Credits="150" Points="0" Quantity="300" Type="3" StockType="1" ItemType="0"/>
<Item Id="10000016" Item="300005030" Credits="150" Points="0" Quantity="300" Type="3" StockType="1" ItemType="0"/>
<Item Id="10000017" Item="300005023" Credits="150" Points="0" Quantity="300" Type="3" StockType="1" ItemType="0"/>
<Item Id="10000018" Item="100003063" Credits="50" Points="0" Quantity="300" Type="3" StockType="1" ItemType="0"/>
<Item Id="10000019" Item="400006005" Credits="0" Points="65000" Quantity="300" Type="3" StockType="1" ItemType="0"/>
<Item Id="10000020" Item="601002007" Credits="0" Points="16000" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="2" ItemType="1"/>
</List>
```

Парсер:

```charp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using Core.Model;

namespace Core.Data.Parsers
{
    public class GoodsParser
    {
        public static Dictionary<int, Good> goods = new Dictionary<int, Good>();

        public static void Load()
        {
            String path = "Data//Goods.xml";
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            if (fileStream.Length != 0L)
            {
                try
                {
                    xmlDocument.Load((Stream)fileStream);
                    for (XmlNode xmlNode1 = xmlDocument.FirstChild; xmlNode1 != null; xmlNode1 = xmlNode1.NextSibling)
                    {
                        if ("List".Equals(xmlNode1.Name))
                        {
                            for (XmlNode xmlNode2 = xmlNode1.FirstChild; xmlNode2 != null; xmlNode2 = xmlNode2.NextSibling)
                            {
                                if ("Item".Equals(xmlNode2.Name))
                                {
                                    XmlNamedNodeMap xmlNamedNodeMap = xmlNode2.Attributes;
                                    Good good = new Good
                                    {
                                        good_id = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("Id").Value),
                                        item_id = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("Item").Value),
                                        priceCredits = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("Credits").Value),
                                        pricePoints = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("Points").Value),
                                        quantity = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("Quantity").Value),
                                        type = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("Type").Value),
                                        stockType = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("StockType").Value),
                                        ItemType = int.Parse(xmlNamedNodeMap.GetNamedItem("ItemType").Value),
                                    };

                                    goods.Add(good.getGoodId(), good);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Logger.Info("[Shop] Loaded {0} goods", goods.Count);
                }
                catch (XmlException ex)
                {
                    Logger.Info("Error {0}", ex);
                }
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас в файле ровно 20 айтемов. если один убрать - остается 19. в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: В файле до этого я прописывал и 26 и 28 итемов,но парсер прогружал только 21.

Comment: тогда приведите пример проблемного файла

Answer (score 1):

У вас в файле есть такая запись:

```
<item Id="10000014" Item="1001001033" Credits="0" Points="1" Quantity="100" Type="1" StockType="2" ItemType="6"/>
```

Обратите внимание, что `item` -- с маленькой буквы. Меж тем как используемое вами сравнение различает регистр:

```
"Item".Equals(xmlNode2.Name)
```

Если в файле могут встречаться тэги как `Item`, так и `item`, то сравнивайте имена без учета регистра:

```
"Item".Equals(xmlNode2.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Аналогично и с остальными сравнениями.

P.S. А вообще почитайте, как правильно считывать xml файлы. Ваш код можно переписать намного проще и понятнее.